# Save information entered into a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

I have added an "edit" and an "add" button to my `UITableView`. How can I save what the user deletes or adds?

Answer (score 0):

Your `UITableView` is fed from some sort of data source, probably a `NSArray`. So just remove the items that have been deleted from the data source.

It's pretty hard to give you any help since you haven't posted any code, or told us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Don't worry about that, your spelling mistakes aren't a problem. This site is not a site to get other people to write your code for you, its for developers to get help with coding problems. When you get stuck while writing code, before coming here, check Apple's documentation, google around, and then if you are still stuck, then come post here.

Comment: Again, you haven't given us enough information. Where is the data in your `UITableView` coming from?